# Facebook logout button asp.net website

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, facebook, visual-studio-2012

I integrated facebook connect to my asp.net website using the code from facebook for developers and I successfully logged in to my website. What I want to do is to have logout button next to the user's name. But what I have is for example "Mark Kent uses 'name of app'. Instead, I want "Welcome, Mark Kent" (logout button). What should I add to my code to accomplish this? Or at least point me out some useful sites about this, because I can't seem to find one.

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:azure">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '4878189xxxxxx', // App ID
        channelUrl: '//http://localhost:xxxxx/channel.html', // Channel File
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Here we subscribe to the auth.authResponseChange JavaScript event. This event is fired
    // for any authentication related change, such as login, logout or session refresh. This means that
    // whenever someone who was previously logged out tries to log in again, the correct case below 
    // will be handled. 
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
        // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
            // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they 
            // have logged in to the app.
            testAPI();


        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            // In this case, the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app, so we call
            // FB.login() to prompt them to do so. 
            // In real-life usage, you wouldn't want to immediately prompt someone to login 
            // like this, for two reasons:
            // (1) JavaScript created popup windows are blocked by most browsers unless they 
            // result from direct interaction from people using the app (such as a mouse click)
            // (2) it is a bad experience to be continually prompted to login upon page load.
            FB.login();

        } else {
            // In this case, the person is not logged into Facebook, so we call the login() 
            // function to prompt them to do so. Note that at this stage there is no indication
            // of whether they are logged into the app. If they aren't then they'll see the Login
            // dialog right after they log in to Facebook. 
            // The same caveats as above apply to the FB.login() call here.
            FB.login();
        }
    });
};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function (d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));

// Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful. 
// This testAPI() function is only called in those cases. 
function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function (response) {
        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
} 
</script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">    
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>     
</form>
</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this solution, and works like a charm. :)

[Solution link](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/04/aspnet-integrate-facebook-login.html)